my react native project have download function . It was downloaded successfully but downloaded file can't open. downloaded files are pdf and excel.why
const downloadFile = async (type) => {
setLoading(true);
const permission_check = Platform.OS === 'android' ? await checkWritePermission() : true;
if (permission_check) {
let fileName = 'invoice_report_' + type + '_' + moment(new Date()).format('DD-MM-YYYY-HH-MM') + (type === 'pdf' ? '.pdf' : '.xlsx');
console.log('file name ---->', fileName)
let path;
const OsVer = Platform.constants['Release'];
if (OsVer >= 12) {
path = ${RNFS.ExternalDirectoryPath}/${fileName};
} else {
path = ${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/${fileName};
}
  const fileUrl = `${baseURL}feesnew/invoice_report_excel_pdf/?type=${type}`;
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': type === 'pdf' ? 'application/pdf' : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
    'Authorization': `${apiClient.headers.Authorization}`
  };
  console.log(`Starting download from ${fileUrl} to ${path}`);

  try {
    const downloadResult = await RNFS.downloadFile({
      fromUrl: fileUrl,
      toFile: path,
      headers: headers
    }).promise;

    if (downloadResult.statusCode === 200) {
      console.log('File downloaded successfully', downloadResult);

      RNFS.readFile(path, 'base64')
        .then((fileContent) => {
          console.log('File content (first 100 chars):', fileContent.slice(0, 100));

          const destinationPath = `${RNFS.DownloadDirectoryPath}/${fileName}`;
          RNFS.moveFile(path, destinationPath)
            .then(() => {
              console.log(`File ${fileName} moved successfully to ${destinationPath}`);

              if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                Share.share({
                  url: `file://${destinationPath}`,
                  type: type === 'pdf' ? 'application/pdf' : 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
                  message: 'Check this file'
                });
              } else {
                ToastAndroid.show('File downloaded successfully', ToastAndroid.LONG);
              }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log(`Error moving file ${fileName}: ${error}`);
              ToastAndroid.show(`Error moving file: ${error.message}`, ToastAndroid.LONG);
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('Error reading downloaded file content:', error);
          ToastAndroid.show('An error occurred while reading the downloaded file.', ToastAndroid.LONG);
        });
    } else {
      console.log('File download failed with status code', downloadResult.statusCode);
      ToastAndroid.show('Failed to download file. Please try again.', ToastAndroid.LONG);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error downloading file:', error);
    ToastAndroid.show('An error occurred while downloading the file.', ToastAndroid.LONG);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
} else {
  console.log('Storage permission denied');
  setLoading(false);
}

};
I wanted open both excel and pdf files after it download
